# Pulling data from a remote mySQL database, using AsyncTask; only displaying very last table row

Tags: android, database, parsing, android-asynctask

As the title says really. I have two columns. I want to put them into textviews so I did it. However only the bottom two results, one from each column gets shown. Very odd. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/qNgfHfT3

The parsing/onPostExecute is towards the bottom where the issue is.

One thing to note: The logs labeled "work" & "dontwork" show all my results, however the logs in the onPostExecute (Google & Google1) only show the last result so I presume the error is in the transfer from parsing to displaying.

Would really appreciate any help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are receiving a JSON response I'd suggest you to parse it by using Gson. It's strongly recommendable as long as you can parse the whole thing in a pair of lines.
Note that creating a proper object it is as easy as doing the following:

```
YourObject object = gson.fromJson(responseReader, YourObject.class);
```

or even if you are retrieving a list of items:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<YourObject>>() {}.getType();
List<YourObject> objects = gson.fromJson(responseReader, listType);
```

[Here's](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-parsing-json-data-with-gson/) an example that fits exactly your needs

After the process is done you'll have your object (or list of objects) available in an accesible variable.

**EDIT:**
First your Asynctask should have the following params:

```
public class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Driver>> {
```

and your doInBackground method will need to pass that array to your onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<Driver> doInBackground(Void... params) {
```

For the rest, I take it when the JSon parsing starts.

```
//PARSING JSON DATA
try {
    JSONObject json_data;
    Driver d;

    jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    int l = jArray.length();

    if(l>0){
        ArrayList<Driver> drivers = newArrayListList<Driver>();

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {

            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            d = new Driver(json_data.optString("Driver_full_name"), json_data.optString("Drives_for"));
            drivers.add(d);

            Log.i("work", returnString);
            Log.i("dontwork", somethingelse);

        }

   } catch (JSONException e1) {
       Log.d("DB", "Error somewhere");
       CurrentSeasonDrivers_DriverName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(CurrentSeasonDrivers_DriversName, "Could not parse data so shut up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
   }
   return drivers;
}

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Drivers>... drivers) {

   Log.i("Google", returnString);
   Log.i("Google1", somethingelse);

   String firstDriverName = drivers.get(0).name;
   String firstDriverDrivesFor = drivers.get(0).drivesfor;

   String secondDriverName = drivers.get(1).name;

   TextView drivername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DriverName);
   drivername.setText(firstDriverName);

   TextView drivesfor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DrivesFor);
   drivesfor.setText(firstDriverDrivesFor);

}
```

With this and an object for your driver will complete the circle.

```
public class Driver{

    public String name;
    public String drivesfor;

    public Driver(String _name, String _drivesfor){
        name = _name;
        drivesfor = _drivesfor;
    }

}
```

I guess you can take over from here.
Let me know about your progress.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue in JSON? I've learnt a fair bit so I'd prefer to use that. Obviously if there isn't then I will look into GSON.

Comment: There's of course a way, but even if you spent some time on JSON it'll still be worth to go to Gson. As well taking into account that it's more efficient than the former.

Comment: And you won't need to go over all those for loops yourself. I'd encourage you to have a look to the link I sent you, and if it doesn't make you extremely happy, I'll help you with the JSON approach.

Comment: Fair enough I'll take a look.

Comment: Hmm, just taking a look at this at the moment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html - Seems like you have to have quite a few classes though(java files); what I'm building is going to have a lot of classes so it might end up being a real mess. Prefer JSON for now but will slowly continue towards GSON and make transition in the future

Comment: To be honest the reason I want to do it in JSON right now is so I can get it working. Once I get my app ready to go I will definitely be looking to make it more efficient. I reckon I can learn more Android/Java too.

Comment: You are overwriting all the time your properties returnString and somethingelse, that's why in onPostExecute you just have the last values. I doubt if what you are retrieving are part of something you can convert in objects. If yes I'd create a List of objects, instantiating one on each loop and adding them to the mentioned list, which should be passed as a parameter to onPostExecute. I don't know if that's explanatory but it's definitely the reason why you just get the last values, and the way to go. If it's still unclear I'll put some code for you.

Comment: Interesting because before I had this code; I had this code: http://pastebin.com/W6s9RF7V if you look at the bottom I have a List and it worked for one column. But only one column. I couldn't get the 2nd column from the database to display.That's why I went down his route because I got two columns here, but only one row.

Comment: Correct, you need a combination of both approaches: either a List of nameValuePairs or your own custom objects or two arrays (one for each column). It's not necessary to tell that the recommended approach would be to create an array of custom objects or nameValuePairs in case the behave more like a pair of values that need to go together.

Comment: the problem I had was when I tried to use two List<String>'s. I can't return more than one string even though I need to have each column in a different string. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: Yes, don't use a List of Strings, use a List of objects (ideally) or a list of String value pair if you want the fast solution.
Pass a (List<NameValuePair> objects) or a (List<YourCustomObject> objects) to your onPostExecute

Comment: How would I do that? Declare everything the same was as List<String>? One thing I have managed is to show both columns, except they show in one line, as in driver1, drivesfor2, driver2, drivesfor2, driver3, drivesfor3 all in one line. If I can get it to read in a column format instead of a row format I reckon this method would work.

Comment: Nice to hear that, it looks like I'm part of Gson, but the truth is that it worked pretty easily and efficiently for me. So I tell you.

Comment: I've just tried your code and I'm getting errors. I will be moving to gson but it's just nice to see it working since the code is already there. In the onPostExecute did you mean to define it "ArrayList<Drivers>", with the S. Problem is if I try to change that back to "Driver" it tells me that I should change the drivers.get statements below that to drivers.get.length, which doesn't work. Maybe define Drivers as a variable?

Comment: Honestly I didn't tried the code :S, could be that there is some glitch. The idea is to pass an array of drivers as a parameter to onPostExecute (the variable name is "drivers") and "Driver" is your object type. drivers is already a variable. Can you tell me which errors do you get? If you don't get it to work I can try your whole code at night.

Comment: Sure, so for this bit of code ""protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Drivers>... drivers) when I attempt to change "Drivers" to "Driver" the object I get the following error "Drivers cannot be resolved to a type". It offers to change it to "Driver" but that creates errors further down. For each "drivers.get()" I get the following error "Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type ArrayList<CurrentSeasonDrivers_DriverName.Driver>[]" and it offers to change it to "get" to "length". That creates furthur errors though so it can't be that. Here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/mqhTQ35C

Comment: Agg shit, right. The piece of ArrayList<Driver> is right (without the s) because is your object type. The wrong piece is that the ArrayList is within the first array position of drivers. So at any place you see "drivers" change it by "drivers[0]" and should work.

Comment: Quite possible that I'm doing this wrong but doing that caused more errors. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/RjStUuXk the errors are in the onPostExecute at the .get() "Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type ArrayList<CurrentSeasonDrivers_DriverName.Driver>[]"

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not being completely explicit, but you shouldn't change the header. The header remains like this:
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Driver>... drivers) {

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line of code: "ArrayList<Driver> drivers[0] = newArrayListList<Driver>();" Obviously I added the 0 but the error is a syntax one, it claims I need 3 brackets. That doesn't help nor does it make any sense. Weird one. Tried cleaning the project

Comment: You only need drivers[0] whenever you are using the param ArrayList<Driver>... drivers. In rest of them just use it the normal way (without the 0)

Comment: Hmm Here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/V8TRnWg3 The only error is still that syntax one, specifically it says "Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token" I've tried a few things but nothing solves that.

Comment: Line 124. ArrayList<Driver> drivers = newArrayListList<Driver>();

Comment: It has to be like this:
ArrayList<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();

Comment: funnily enough that specific error fixed itself. I got an error telling me I couldn't return "drivers", to solve that I declared drivers as an arraylist at the top of my code, here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/TQMWEzVV The code now has no errors but when I ran the app didn't display any data. json_string gets the json but it doesn't get parsed. I can't check an array within a log so I'm lost after that.

Comment: It'll be easier if we spend some minutes in the chat. There are still some errors.

Comment: fair enough, let me know when you are free to chat.

Comment: At night. Something around 9pm CEST

Comment: Thanks a lot! 8pm my time (UK).

Comment: Free to chat now. Let me know when you are, I'll be here for a while anyway

Comment: cant' see you..can you look for me?

Comment: This link should work http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16380/discussion-between-red-and-jose-l-ugia